# Using CORS JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new JS. I have doubt in my mind. Using js can we make cross domain requests like this ?

For an example

There are two sites

Site A - I own this site

Site B - I do not have any control over this site.

And...

I want to make a script like this

If user comes and if he can access site B, then he can have access to site A.

Otherwise i will show him a blank html page.

Is this possible? I hope you all have a great day! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean *"if he can access site B"*?

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear. I meant if he get response code 200 to site B. Then show my site.

Comment: If site B allows requests from your domain, then yes, otherwise no - period. At least as long as your application runs in a browser that respects CORS.

Comment: CORS has to be set on the server, if you can not access it, you can not use CORs

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering :). I checked it more and luk2302 you were right and that was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To create secure sites, you need that Site B understand that site A is a secure and know origin, otherwise you're letting open the door of your sites.

You actually can enable CORS and allow the communication between boths sites, but again is a very bad practice, some services will not work correctly.

Comment: *"You actually can enable CORS and allow the communication between boths sites"* - no, OP cannot do that if he does not control site B. And care to elaborate why it is *"very bad practice"*?